# PDFTron UWP calibration issue

Tags: uwp, pdftron

downloaded PDFTron SamplePDFViewer and once application is deployed we are facing following problem
1)Using a measurement tool, when we measure a entity and then calibrate, the new scale and unit gets applied to the selected entity only.It does not get applied to the subsequent measurement entities we draw on the pdf

NOTE: This functionality is working for Android, xamrin and web platforms but not working on uwp platform

Do anyone know the solution

Sample Link: [Sample Code](https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-uwp-samples)

Answer (score 0):

A fix has been made for this issue and the nightly builds can be found [here](https://www.pdftron.com/nightly/#experimental/)